# Where can i get total list of all existent Etehereum contract ABIs?

Tags: abi

We all know that exists https://www.4byte.directory/ where we can get mapping (function selector) -> (function signatures). Is there a dataset where I can get mapping (contract address) -> (JSON contract abi) without any web requests? If there is no such one, is there any ways to create such. For example by creating similar to 4byte directory service, but for contract addresses will it be popular enough to gather some data?